# In Python, create an array based on an expression and specific interval

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.7

I need to create a program in python in which I ask the user for the number of intervals they want, and the specific interval [a,b] of the array. From that, I need to create the elements of the array based on an expression (b-a)/n.

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
n= int(input("Enter the number of intervals: "))
a= float(input("Enter the min point of the interval: "))
b= float(input("Enter the max point of the interval: "))

xPoints=list() #create a list of the x points
xPoints.append(float(a))

#code for elements in between a and b

xPoints.append(float(b))
print(xPoints)
```

Any help with the array will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_array(n, a, b):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    elif n == 1:
        return [a, b]
    else:
        return [a] + [a+i*((b-a)/n) for i in range(1, n)] + [b]

n = int(input("Enter the number of intervals: "))
a = float(input("Enter the lowest number of the interval: "))
b = float(input("Enter the highest number of the interval: "))

print(get_array(n, a, b))
```